# how to prevent click or selection on node in tree list extjs 7.1 modern

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, treegrid, treelist

I want to prevent click or select event on some treelist node so user can not click or select that particular node. I have tried disabled property but it's not working in modern and I'm using version 7.1 of ExtJs.

All is my root node and I want to prevent click or select on the red text node.

[image]

Comment: Can you update the details with the code you have already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `itemclick` listener (see [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/modern/Ext.list.Tree.html#event-itemclick)) to the `Ext.list.Tree`, and return `false` to prevent expand and select for a particular item:

```
xtype: 'treelist',
listeners: {
  itemclick(sender, info, eOpts) {
    // you will have the item in info.item,
    // so create the condition as you wish
    if (info.item...) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This wont help because when I select another node and the data is loaded on right panel than that data won't get hide I have to explicitly hide, whatever I have done the solution by using CLS of itemTpl, but the problem is it's not working on root node else child nodes are not tappable.

Comment: Please share you code, preferably in a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate the problem so that we can try to help.